# Rebus Handler with TransactionScope

Tags: transactionscope, rebus

I have setup a Rebus handler with a Transaction Scope attached to it to MSMQ and RabbitMQ. The handler handles the first few messages 100%. After a couple of minutes when I try publish new messages to the queue I get the error message below....

What am I doing wrong?

```
    [11:09:59 ERR] An error occurred when attempting to complete the transaction context
    System.Transactions.TransactionAbortedException: The transaction has aborted.
     ---> System.TimeoutException: Transaction Timeout
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Transactions.TransactionStateAborted.BeginCommit(InternalTransaction tx, Boolean asyncCommit, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
       at System.Transactions.CommittableTransaction.Commit()
       at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.InternalDispose()
       at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.Dispose()
       at Rebus.TransactionScopes.TransactionScopeTransportDecorator.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<Receive>b__1(ITransactionContext ctx)
       at Rebus.Transport.TransactionContext.Dispose()
       at Rebus.Transport.TransactionContext.Complete()
       at Rebus.Workers.ThreadPoolBased.ThreadPoolWorker.ProcessMessage(TransactionContext context, TransportMessage transportMessage)
```

```
        // Initialize Class
        _activator = new BuiltinHandlerActivator();
        // Register
        _activator.Register((context, handler) => new Handler(_activator.Bus));
        
        // Configure
        Configure.With(_activator)
            .Logging(logging => logging.Serilog())
            .Options(options =>
            {
                options.HandleMessagesInsideTransactionScope();
                options.SimpleRetryStrategy(maxDeliveryAttempts: 1, secondLevelRetriesEnabled: true);
                options.SetMaxParallelism(5);
                options.SetNumberOfWorkers(5);
            })
```

Comment: You mention both MSMQ and RabbitMQ, but there's no mention of any of them in your Rebus configuration... could you maybe show some more of your configuration?

Comment: Btw.  when you're registering a `Func<IBus, IMessageContext, IHandleMessages>` as a message handler factory, the arguments passed to the factory are `IBus` and `IMessageContext` respectively, so you can go `activator.Register((bus, context) => new MessageHandler(bus));` and thus have the bus injected

Comment: I copied a small portion of the setup in. I see the delivery of the message to the handler still seems to happen even though there is a transaction exception. The transaction abort happens on RabbitMQ. Decided against MSMQ in the end.